# Fortran Compiler Terminology: Dummy Variables and Attributes

Tags: variables, attributes, fortran

Can someone explain to me what sort of an abstraction in the parser / compiler a dummy variable or attribute corresponds to?

```
      PURE SUBROUTINE F(X, Y)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL, INTENT(INOUT) :: X, Y, C
C        REAL :: A, B
C        REAL, SAVE :: C = 3.14E0
        PARAMETER (C = 3.14E0, X = 32, Y = X)
        X = Y + 2 * SIN(Y)
      END
```

---

```
cetin@unique:~/lab/secret/tapenade$ gfortran -x f77 -c 1.f 
1.f:6.37:

        PARAMETER (C = 3.14E0, X = 32, Y = X)                           
                                    1
Error: PARAMETER attribute conflicts with DUMMY attribute in 'x' at (1)
1.f:3.38:

        REAL, INTENT(INOUT) :: X, Y, C                                  
                                     1
Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable
```

---

```
cetin@unique:~/lab/secret/tapenade$ ifort -c 1.f
1.f(3): error #6451: A dummy argument name is required in this context.   [C]
        REAL, INTENT(INOUT) :: X, Y, C
-------------------------------------^
1.f(6): error #6406: Conflicting attributes or multiple declaration of name.   [X]
        PARAMETER (C = 3.14E0, X = 32, Y = X)
-------------------------------^
1.f(6): error #6406: Conflicting attributes or multiple declaration of name.   [Y]
        PARAMETER (C = 3.14E0, X = 32, Y = X)
---------------------------------------^
1.f(6): error #6592: This symbol must be a defined parameter, an enumerator, or an argument of an inquiry function that evaluates to a compile-time constant.   [X]
        PARAMETER (C = 3.14E0, X = 32, Y = X)
-------------------------------------------^
compilation aborted for 1.f (code 1)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fortran passes by reference.  The dummy attribute corresponds to those variables that are passed in to the function (`X` and `Y` in your case).  The parameter statement is expecting something static, but since `X` is whatever is passed into the function, it really doesn't make any sense.  The parameter statement is a way to set up constants - it doesn't have anything to do with the parameters to a subroutine.

When you get the error saying that `C` is not a `DUMMY` variable, then, it means that it's not finding `C` in the list of variables that will be passed into/out of the function - your declaration is only `F(X, Y)`: no `C` in sight.  Though that you are not using the `DUMMY` attribute explicitly, you have the `INTENT(INOUT)` attribute, which means that these variables correspond to subroutine input/output.

To get what you want, you would have a subroutine that looks something like:

```
subroutine F(X, Y)
    implicit none

    ! These are the dummy variables
    real, intent(inout) :: X, Y

    ! These are the variables in the scope of this subroutine
    real                  :: a, b
    real, parameter, save :: c = 3.14E0

    X = Y + 2*sin(Y)
end subroutine F
```

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do - you're declaring a `pure` subroutine, which means a subroutine without side effects, but you are using `intent(inout)` for your variables, which means that `X` and `Y` can be altered in the course of execution.

I'd add as well that inside a subroutine, initializing a variable in its declaration statement like `REAL :: C = 3.14E0` yields a variable with an *implicit* `save` attribute.  If you want it to be saved from call to call, though, you've done the right thing by explicitly adding the `save` attribute to make it clear that that's what you're doing.

I'm not a parser/compiler guy, but I think that to answer your question, the `dummy` attribute means that you're just getting a pointer - you don't have to allocate any space, since the variable used in the function call already has space allocated.

Answer (score 6):

The actual problem with the call is well explained by Tim Whitcomb. I will try to explain more explicitly the terms.

**Dummy argument** is a Fortran specific term. It is what other languages call *formal parameters* or similar, i.e. it is the object that is called `X` and `Y` (in your case) and witch gets associated to an **actual argument** when the procedure is called.

Therefore in:

```
subroutine s(i)
  integer :: i
end

call s(1)
```

the `i` is a dummy argument of the subroutine `s` while the expression `1` is the actual argument which is passed to the subroutine to the dummy argument `i`.

**Attributes** are a form of specifying additional properties of data objects or procedures. The attributes can be specified using statements:

```
real c
intent(in) c
optional c
```

or they can be specified in a single declaration:

```
real, intent(in), optional :: c
```

This way the dummy argument `c` is a default real with attributes `intent(in)` and `optional`.

*Conflicting attributes* are attributes that can't be specified for one object at the same time. Your example with `intent(...)` and `parameter` serves well. These are incompatible as the first implies a dummy argument and the other specifies a *named constant*.